# What should be my hive partitioning strategy and view strategy so that query can efficiently run and return results within 10 seconds

Tags: hive, bigdata, data-warehouse, presto, data-partitioning

My use case is i have two data sources:
1. Source1 (as speed layer)
2. Hive external table on top of S3(as batch layer)

I am using Presto for querying data from both the data sources by using view.
I want to create view that will union data from both the sources like : **"create view test as select * from Source1.table union all select * from hive.table"**

We are keeping 24 hours data in Source1 and after 24 hours that data will be migrated to s3 via hive.

Columns for Source1 tables are:timestamp,logtype,company,category

User will query data using timestamp range(can query data of last 15/30 minutes, last x hours, last x days, last x months, etc)
example: **"select * from test where timestamp > (now() - interval '15' minute)","select * from test where timestamp > (now() - interval '12' hour)", "select * from test where timestamp > (now() - interval '1' day)"**

To satisfy the user query I need to partition the hive table as well as the user should not be aware of the underlying stategy i.e if user is querying **last x minutes data**, he/she should not bother that if presto is reading the data from Source1 or hive.

**What should be my hive partitioning strategy and view strategy so that query can efficiently run and return results within 10 seconds?**

Answer (score 1):

For hive a partition column should be used which will queried in filter.
In your case this is timestamp. However if you use timestamp it would create a partition for every second (or millisecond) depending in the data in the column.
A better solution would be to create columns like `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour` (from timestamp) and to use these as partition columns.

The same strategy will work for Kudu however be advised it could create hot-spotting since all the newly arriving records will go to same (most-recent) partition this will limit insert (and may be query) performance.
To overcome use one additional column as hash partition along with timestamp derived columns.
e.g `year`, `month`,  `day`, `hour`, `logtype`

Comment: Since you must use timestamp as the only filter criteria, you are limited to using timestamp as the partition. But creating partition for every timestamp (second) will create too many partitions in hive and will be bad for performance.